# Applying multiple formats to same data in excel using perl

Tags: excel, perl, formatting, format

I have a situation where I am writing data to an Excel file using [Excel::Writer::XLSX](https://metacpan.org/pod/Excel::Writer::XLSX) with Perl. I have records stored as comma delimited strings in an array. For example:

```
$array[0] = "col1_value,col2_value,col3_value,col4_value" # row 1
$array[1] = "col1_value,col2_value,col3_value,col4_value" # row 2
.
.
$array[$n]                                                # row n
```

Now I have to display these data in Excel with center alignment,border and bg_color. So I have done the below:

```
my $general_format = $workbook->add_format(
border => 1,
bg_color => 31,
align => 'center'
);
```

And then I have put a loop on the array and after splitting it, I am putting all columns of each record in excel as below:

```
Loop on array of records{
$worksheet->write_row( $i+2, 0, $recordRef, $general_format );
}
```

But I am facing issue that col1 & col2 of each record has numbers whereas col3 & col4 are percentage/date, etc. I need the numbers to be formatted in comma-separated format. If I do the below, the output is fine but when we click the col3/col4 cell in Excel, it converts the percentage/date to number format:

```
my $general_format = $workbook->add_format(
border => 1,
bg_color => 31,
align => 'center',
num_format => '#,##0'
);
```

Is there any way to apply the `num_format => '#,##0'` format specifically on col1 & col2 along with the rest of the formatting done on col1 & col2(the color/alignment/etc) as the data being written is row(record)-wise?

I need col1 and col2 to have below formats:

```
border => 1,
bg_color => 31,
align => 'center',
num_format => '#,##0'
```

and col3 and col4 to have below formats:

```
border => 1,
bg_color => 31,
align => 'center'
```

But I can write data record wise only(using [`write_row()`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Excel::Writer::XLSX#write_row(-$row,-$column,-$array_ref,-$format-))), not column by column.

Comment: Why can you only write it per row? Is that part of the program out of your hands?

Comment: It would be useful to have actual example data. Please [edit] your question and include a couple of rows of real data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot pass multiple formats to the `write_row` method. However, you can set a default format for each column before you write the row with [`set_column`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Excel::Writer::XLSX#set_column(-$first_col,-$last_col,-$width,-$format,-$hidden,-$level,-$collapsed-)).

Here's a short example.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Excel::Writer::XLSX;
 
my $workbook = Excel::Writer::XLSX->new( 'perl.xlsx' );
my $worksheet = $workbook->add_worksheet();

my $general_format = $workbook->add_format(
    border => 1,
    bg_color => 31,
    align => 'center',
);

my $num_format = $workbook->add_format();
$num_format->copy($general_format); # we have to copy the other format options
$num_format->set_num_format('#.##0');

# set column formats up front
$worksheet->set_column( 'A:B', undef, $num_format);
$worksheet->set_column( 'C:D', undef, $general_format);

my @records = (
    [qw/ 1.1 11.111 1% 2017-12-05/],
    [qw/ 2.2 22.222 2.2% 2017-12-05/],
    [qw/ 3.3 33.333 3.33% 2017-12-05/],
    [qw/ 4.4 44.444 4.444% 2017-12-05/],
);
my $i = 1;
foreach my $record ( @records) {
    $worksheet->write_row( $i, 0, $record ); # no more format here
    ++$i;
}
```

This is what it will look like (with the Excel Viewer).

[image: Example Excel file output]

It's important to note that `set_column` only writes a format if there is no other format present in a cell.

> The `$format` parameter will be applied to any cells in the column that don't have a format.

You also need to take care of the order in which formats are applied.

> If you wish to define a column format in this way you should call the method before any calls to write(). If you call it afterwards it won't have any effect.
>
> A default row format takes precedence over a default column format

Comment: Thanks simbabque! I find your answer really useful for me.
Just to add, meanwhile I also found an alternative:

    `$worksheet->conditional_formatting( 'C:F',
    {
    type     => 'cell',
    criteria => 'greater than',
    value    => 999,
    format   => $number_format,
    }
    );`

Comment: @Ashu you didn't say anything about the real values. There's no way we could have come up with that as a solution. Always give complete information. Don't leave stuff out please.